# Python overflow adding

Tags: python, binary, decimal, overflow

I'm trying to write a Python function which takes two integers and a number of bits. The function adds the two numbers together within the specified number of bits. It then prints the addition of the two numbers and shows the answer as in the examples below. It must also print the word "stackoverflow" if the addition in the specified number of bits causes the overflow condition.

add_overflow(1, -1, 2) results in 01 + 11 = 00

and add_overflow(1, 1, 2) results in 01 + 01 = 10 overflow

Comment: Show some attempt. Note that not all integer types out there would have to be signed, so be careful to qualify that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_overflow(a,b,num_bits):
   rangeMax = 2**(num_bits - 1) # unsigned range
   result = a + b
   if result >= rangeMax:
      return str((result) % rangeMax) + "stackoverflow"
   else:
      return result
```

This assumes that the numbers would be signed (based on the example you gave). If your numbers are unsigned use `result > rangeMax`.

If you want the utility to just mention overflow and not restrict the data to n bits you can drop the mod part from the result. `return str(result) + " stackoverflow"`

If you want the final result in binary (not sure why) you can do `return "{0:b}".format(result) + "overflow"`